# Display different columns in GridView for different SQL queries

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, gridview

If GridView is bound to a SqlDataScource control, which has a select statement, GridView will produce an error if that select statement is later changed programmatically to select a different set of columns, the error is

> 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name [An Expected Column Name]

How could one execute different select statements from time to time that return different columns and display their results in a GridView ?

Thanks

Comment: I've never done something like that but maybe you could check if the `AutoGenerateColumns` of the grid is set to true or before the binding, check if you have to add or remove elements from `Grid.Columns`